# On comparing the metrics $d(f,g)=\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)| dt$ and $d'(f,g)= \sup_{t\in[a,b]} |f(t)-g(t)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to answer a problem where I should compare the following metrics, with $d$ defined on the set of continuous functions $f,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ and $d'$ defined on the set of bounded continuous functions $f,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$

$$d(f,g)=\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)| dt \hspace{3cm} d'(f,g)= \sup_{t\in[a,b]} |f(t)-g(t)|$$

Can they be compared? I tried two examples:

$$f(t)=\sin t \quad g(t)=0  \hspace{3cm} F(t)=2t \quad G(t)=0$$

Using $d,d'$ in the first pair of functions, with $a=0, b=\pi$, I get:

$$d(f,g)=\int_{0}^{\pi}|sin(t)|=\int_{0}^{\pi}sin(t) =2 \quad \geq\quad d'(F,G)=\sup_{t\in[0,\pi]} |sin(t)|=1$$

Using $d,d'$ in the second pair of functions, with $a=0, b=1$, I get:

$$d(f,g)=\int_{0}^{1}|2t|=\int_{0}^{1}2t =1 \quad \leq\quad d'(F,G)=\sup_{t\in[0,1]} |2t|=2$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare" exactly? Is it to test if they are equivalent? You've correctly disproved that already.

Comment: You get that $d(f,g)\leq (b-a) d’(f,g)$ when both distances are defined.

Comment: @BhorisDhanjal It's not too clear for me too. I thought I should show if $d\leq d'$ or $d\geq d'$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This is really nice. How do we prove that?

Comment: If $h_1\leq h_2,$ then $\int_a^b h_1\leq \int_a^b h_2.$ It’s really direct. If $|f-g|$ has upper bound $M$ then use $h_1=|f-g|$ and $h_2=M,$ the constant function.

Comment: Bounded continuous functions $f,g:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ is redundant. Continuous functions defined on a compact interval are bounded.

Comment: To compare the metrics take a look at the unit balls around $0$.